# Is using custom element without actually defining dangerous?

Tags: html, custom-element

Instead defining:

```
<div id="my-custom-element-101"></div>
```

I wrote:

```
<my-custom-element-101></my-custom-element-101>
```

But didn't go further to extend HTMLElement and define it. This way I get some enhanced readability and don't need to do any further coding.

Is there any potential downside to this practice?

Comment: No downside. Little known browser **W3C standard** fact is that (if the element is in the global DOM) the ``id`` actually creates a **global** variable with the same name; so you 'loose' a short-cut for not having to use ``document.getElementById('...')``  And...also W3C standard.. duplicate IDs... return an Array of your elements.. so no need for ``.querySelectorAll(..)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no absolute downside for that, as soon as you use valid custom element notation (i.e. a name with an hyphen "`-`").

In this case it's just an *unknown* custom element.

Of course if someone else decide to define a custom element with the same name you could get into some troubles but if you own the entire code of the page it can't happen.

Also note that, in your example, your tag `<my-custom-element-101`> is seen as an inline element, not a block.